# How to set Azure App Service Stack and Platform via ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I want to set Azure's App Service Platform and Stack settings with ARM template.
What should be added to ARM template to set those values?

I want to be able to set .NET version to .NET Core 3.1 and Platform to x64 or x32.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `siteConfig` block within `properties`, add the following:

```json
      "metadata": [ 
        { 
          "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
          "value": "dotnetcore" 
        } 
      ],
      "use32BitWorkerProcess": false,
```

Comment: Do you know values for other stacks?

Comment: If you want .Net 5, remove the `metadata` block and use `"netFrameworkVersion": "v5.0"` instead.  Your best bet is to set it manually via the portal and the use either the Export Template option or the Resource Explorer to determine what to use in the ARM template.